# Generated structs from protos gives pointers that I can't use

Tags: go, pointers, protocol-buffers

I created my structs using protobuf and now I can not use a nested struct because it is a pointer. The problem I can't change the proto file. I have to use what is generated. Does anyone have a workaround to my problem? I figure it should be pretty simple.

Here is the generated struct:

```golang
type Dashboard struct {
    Id                   string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name                 string   `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=name,proto3" json:"name,omitempty"`
    Description          string   `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=description,proto3" json:"description,omitempty"`
    Hidden               bool     `protobuf:"varint,4,opt,name=hidden,proto3" json:"hidden,omitempty"`
    Layout               *Layout  `protobuf:"bytes,5,opt,name=layout,proto3" json:"layout,omitempty"`
    IsCanned             bool     `protobuf:"varint,6,opt,name=is_canned,json=isCanned,proto3" json:"is_canned,omitempty"`
    UserId               string   `protobuf:"bytes,7,opt,name=user_id,json=userId,proto3" json:"user_id,omitempty"`
    Shared               bool     `protobuf:"varint,8,opt,name=shared,proto3" json:"shared,omitempty"`
    DisplayTitle         bool     `protobuf:"varint,9,opt,name=display_title,json=displayTitle,proto3" json:"display_title,omitempty"`
    TenantId             string   `protobuf:"bytes,10,opt,name=tenant_id,json=tenantId,proto3" json:"tenant_id,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}

type Layout struct {
    GridItems            []*GridItem `protobuf:"bytes,1,rep,name=grid_items,json=gridItems,proto3" json:"grid_items,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{}    `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte      `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32       `json:"-"`
}

type GridItem struct {
    Id                   string   `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"id,omitempty"`
    ViewId               string   `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=view_id,json=viewId,proto3" json:"view_id,omitempty"`
    Cols                 int32    `protobuf:"varint,3,opt,name=cols,proto3" json:"cols,omitempty"`
    Rows                 int32    `protobuf:"varint,4,opt,name=rows,proto3" json:"rows,omitempty"`
    X                    int32    `protobuf:"varint,5,opt,name=x,proto3" json:"x,omitempty"`
    Y                    int32    `protobuf:"varint,6,opt,name=y,proto3" json:"y,omitempty"`
    XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{} `json:"-"`
    XXX_unrecognized     []byte   `json:"-"`
    XXX_sizecache        int32    `json:"-"`
}
```

And when I try to create a new dashboard I can't assign Layout to it because it is a pointer.

```golang
dashboard := &types.Dashboard{
    Id:           uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4()).String(),
    Name:         request.Name,
    Description:  request.Description,
    Hidden:       request.Hidden,
    Layout:       request.Layout,
    IsCanned:     request.IsCanned,
    Shared:       request.Shared,
    DisplayTitle: request.DisplayTitle,
    UserId:       tokenValues.UserID,
    TenantId:     tokenValues.TenantID,
}
```

Comment: You are trying to assign a value to a pointer. Without knowing what `request.Layout` actually is, try assigning `&request.Layout`.

Comment: @MichaelKrupp Yes I tried it, but it still doesn't assign

Comment: To your question, please add the type of Request, and the specific error message you get. To improve the question, you could remove a lot of it -- most of the protobuf fields are not relevant to your problem, so the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example can be quite short.

Answer (score 0):

you can use struct reference like below.

```
func main() {
    grids := []*GridItem{
        &GridItem{
            Id: "grid_1",
        },
    }
    layout := &Layout{
        GridItems: grids,
    }
    dashboard := Dashboard{
        Layout: layout,
    }
    fmt.Println(dashboard.Layout.GridItems[0].Id)
}
//Output: grid_1
```

you can run [here](https://play.golang.org/p/HvDVQ4L1GBp)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to:

```golang
dashboard := &Dashboard{
    Id: ...,
    Name: ...,
    Description: ...,
    Hidden: ...,
    Layout: &request.Layout,
    IsCanned: ...,
    Shared: ...,
    DisplayTitle: ...,
    UserId: ...,
    TenantId: ...,
}
```

> **NOTE** The `&` (address of) prefixing `request.Layout`

You often see hierarchical structs created at once rather than (as above) by creating the subcomponents first, because the intent is clearer and it's less cumbersome:

```golang
dashboard := &Dashboard{
    Id: ...,
    Name: ...,
    Description: ...,
    Hidden: ...,
    Layout: &Layout{
        GridItems: []*GridItem{
            &GridItem{
                Id: ...
                ViewId: ...
            },
            &GridItem{
                Id: ...
                ViewId: ...
            },           
        }
    },
    IsCanned: ...,
    Shared: ...,
    DisplayTitle: ...,
    UserId: ...,
    TenantId: ...,
}
```

> **NOTE** The `&GridItem` in `&GridItem{ ... }` may be dropped because the type is unambiguous.